# OpenSSL as a CA without touching the certs/crl/index/etc environment

Tags: openssl, x509

I think I have the right OpenSSL command to sign a certificate but I've gotten stuck and the tutorials I've found use a different argument format (I'm using OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010).

> openssl ca -cert cert.pem -keyfile key.pem

(Private key is not encryped and CSR is on stdin.)

It gives this error

```
Using configuration from /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
./demoCA/index.txt: No such file or directory
unable to open './demoCA/index.txt'
```

Looking at that configuration file:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default    # The default ca section

[ CA_default ]
dir      = ./demoCA        # Where everything is kept
certs    = $dir/certs      # Where the issued certs are kepp
crl_dir  = $dir/crl        # Where the issued crl are kept
database = $dir/index.txt  # database index file.
```

I don't have any of this set up. **I don't want to set any of this up.**

Is it strictly nessecary, or is there a "don't bother" option?

I tried creating empty directories and files but I've got in a tangle. What I really want is for a command like the above to work, with the output on stdout, without touching *anything* on the filesystem.

Comment: I think you might get better responses if you specified your minimum requirements, i.e. would you be satisfied with any solution that given a CA certificate and key can sign a client certificate or does it have to use `openssl ca`? (Not that I know any better answer offhand)

Comment: There is no way around using OpenSSL without setting up your CA, because otherwise how could your sign a cert request? You wouldn't have a CA to do that. ;-)

**Keep in mind that OpenSSL keeps track of which cert requests it saw, and which Certs it signed / revoked, etc... so that's why those directories are needed (you can use the defaults for those paths).**

Comment: I accept that that's part of the *normal* duties of a CA, but an *abnormal* CA which doesn't perform those duties wouldn't need those directories, right?

Comment: @spraff: That depends on what you mean by a "CA", you could just go through the same process as `openssl ca` without the writing to disk stuff and whatever, which is why I asked you to clarify what would constitute a minimal solution for you.

Comment: A minimual solution will generates a certificate which the submitter can use, one which can be validated against the ca's root certificate.  The CA doesn't need to retain any information at all, not for revocation or anything.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't know of any "don't bother" options, but here is how you can setup a quick demo CA:

```
#!/bin/bash
CAROOT=/path/to/ca
mkdir -p ${CAROOT}/ca.db.certs   # Signed certificates storage
touch ${CAROOT}/ca.db.index      # Index of signed certificates
echo 01 > ${CAROOT}/ca.db.serial # Next (sequential) serial number

# Configuration
cat>${CAROOT}/ca.conf<<'EOF'
[ ca ]
default_ca = ca_default

[ ca_default ]
dir = REPLACE_LATER
certs = $dir
new_certs_dir = $dir/ca.db.certs
database = $dir/ca.db.index
serial = $dir/ca.db.serial
RANDFILE = $dir/ca.db.rand
certificate = $dir/ca.crt
private_key = $dir/ca.key
default_days = 365
default_crl_days = 30
default_md = md5
preserve = no
policy = generic_policy
[ generic_policy ]
countryName = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName = optional
organizationName = optional
organizationalUnitName = optional
commonName = supplied
emailAddress = optional
EOF

sed -i "s|REPLACE_LATER|${CAROOT}|" ${CAROOT}/ca.conf

cd ${CAROOT}

# Generate CA private key
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 1024

# Create Certificate Signing Request
openssl req -new -key ca.key  \
                 -out ca.csr       

# Create self-signed certificate
openssl x509 -req -days 10000 \
              -in ca.csr      \
              -out ca.crt     \
              -signkey ca.key
```

Now you can generate and sign keys:

```
# Create private/public key pair
openssl genrsa -out server.key 1024

# Create Certificate Signing Request
openssl req -new -key server.key \
                 -out server.csr

# Sign key
openssl ca -config ${CAROOT}/ca.conf   \
           -in server.csr              \
           -cert ${CAROOT}/ca.crt      \
           -keyfile ${CAROOT}/ca.key   \
           -out server.crt
```

Comment: Here is a howto on  setting up your own CA(http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/be-your-own-ca/), and links to the OpenSSL docs, and SSL Certificates HowTo.  I appreciate this is not the answer you want, but I think you cannot sign a certificate without having a Certificate Authority (with a root certificate setup).  Although section 2.3 of SSL Certificates HOWTO, implies that maybe it could be possible, but not exactly how.

Comment: I wanted to say thanks here, because in this single solution are more answers to OpenSSL questions I've had for years than any other single resource I've ever seen. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what the OP wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 21):

Based on [snow6oy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13047670/399105), here's what I did:

```
openssl x509 -req -CA CACert.pem -CAkey CAKey.pem -CAcreateserial -in YourCSR.csr -out YourCert.pem
```

A couple optional flags that may be useful:

- `-days 1095`
  (The default is 30 days)
- `-sha256`
  (RHEL 7 defaults to SHA-1)

Comment: I tried this, but it produced a self-signed certificate instead. There was no root CA in the chain.

Answer (score 14):

Rather than using the ca option try the x509 option with -req. You would add -CAfile to point to your authority. This will sign your certificate without adding entries to the index. There is more about using x509 as "mini CA" here.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html#Micro-CA-Options

Comment: x509 is so much easier to use for most purposes. I was fighting with req 8 or 9 hours today (on Windows), then I found your answer and solved it in 2 minutes.

Comment: It would be nice to include a command in the command instead of just pointing to the docs that lists hundreds of command line switches.

Comment: especially as the page 404's now