# Android recognizes my self made CA certificate as a user certificate, and does not install it properly

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, certificate-authority

I made my own CA certificate using [OpenSSL as a CA without touching the certs/crl/index/etc environment's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7770075/1346426), and trying to install it using [Add & remove certificates - Nexus Help](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2844832?hl=en).

Android recognizes my certificate as "one user certificate":

[image]

Instead of "one CA certificate", like in this picture (used a downloaded CA certificate):

[image]

Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I used [Creating a CA](https://www.phildev.net/ssl/creating_ca.html) and it worked fine.

To install it on Android though, you need to remove the human readable text fro the output `cacert.pem` and leave only the certificate data, i.e. the one starting with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ending with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`, otherwise Android says "No certificate to install".

I think that the previous guide created a regular certificate and then used it as a CA certificate to sign the server certificate, but I'm only guessing, feel free to correct me.